# Gnome- terminal quits when pressing enter

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am on Ubuntu 16.04. When browsing in the terminal and using various commands the terminal just quits (closes without any message) when pressing enter. I thought maybe I am browsing through folders with too little permissions. When I add permissions it seems better, but even then it still happens.

It happens for sure with: cd into a folder.
Permissions; I did:

```
chown -R usr:usr rootproblemfolder
chmod -R 777 rootproblemfolder
```

Any idea?

I found this, which accurately describes my case, but setting /tmp to chmod 1777 does not help:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211045

Comment: What "various commands" did you use? What permissions did you add when you said you "add permissions"? How did you add said permissions?

Comment: @edwinksl see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my .bashrc file to a pristine one and the problems were gone. Added one by one the lines of my original .bashrc file and found the one causing the issues:

```
### Bashhub.com Installation.
### This Should be at the EOF. https://bashhub.com/docs
if [ -f ~/.bashhub/bashhub.sh ]; then
    source ~/.bashhub/bashhub.sh
fi
```